# How to create a QRadialGradient

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets, qgradient

I am trying to create a circle with a gradient fill:

```cpp
//I want the center to be at 10, 10 in the circle and the radius to be 50 pixels
QRadialGradient radial(QPointF(10, 10), 50);
radial.setColorAt(0, Qt::black); //I want the center to be black
radial.setColorAt(1, Qt::white); //I want the sides to be white
painter.setBrush(QBrush(radial));
painter.drawEllipse(/*stuff*/);
```

However, all this accomplishes is to show me a totally white circle. How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be white because you are using the wrong coordinates.

If you set the gradient for your widget (in your case it's only a small area), you can paint your ellipse in the wrong place, and it will be surely white:

Set the gradient's coordinates correctly. e.g:

```cpp
QRadialGradient radial(QPointF(100, 100), 50);
// ...
painter.drawEllipse(50,50,100,100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```cpp
radial.setColorAt( 0, Qt::black );
```

To:

```cpp
radial.setColorAt( n, Qt::black );
```

`n` being a number between 0 and 1.